# Clion не видит header файлы, GTK3

Tags: c, clion, include, gtk3

При сборке выходит сообщение, мол не видит файл `gtk/gtk.h`. Если указать `gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h` и `gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h` уже на другое ругается.Но самое главное то,что если попытаться собрать через консоль такой вот код:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Всё прекрасно соберётся по команде:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o test test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Работаю в Ubuntu 22.04

---

P.S.

Вывод Cmake:

```
/snap/clion/198/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/snap/clion/198/bin/ninja/linux/ninja -G Ninja -S /home/home-pc/CLionProjects/gtk_PNX -B /home/home-pc/CLionProjects/gtk_PNX/cmake-build-debug
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/home-pc/CLionProjects/gtk_PNX/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(gtk_PNX C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(gtk_PNX main.c)
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Показывайте cmake файл, и вывод cmake

Comment: @user7860670 Обновил вопрос

Comment: В cmake ни одного упоминания библиотеки gtk нет. Не удивительно, что ничего не работает.

Comment: @user7860670 А Cmake разве сам не подтягивает файлы упомянутые в main.c?

Comment: Плюс пробежался по всем возможным папкам и не нашёл ничего типа `gtk/gtk.h`, только 
`gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h` . Это я про то, раз уж нужно будет указывать директорию, её сначала надо найти))

Comment: Оно наоборот работает. Чтобы компилятор мог найти файлы, упомянутые в `main.c`, они должны явным образом подключаться в cmake.

Comment: Сейчас проверил, в проект подгружаются пути трёх папок include и ни в одной из них нет совпадения `gtk/gtk.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заполнил `CMakeLists.txt` таким образом:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project (gtk_dt C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(gtk_dt main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gtk_dt ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

И всё заработало... [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) спасибо за наводку